# Convert static SQL to dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a static SQL query which finds out blank counts and data types (whether numeric or alphanumeric etc). Below is the query:

```
SELECT
case when Pattern = '' then 'BLANK' else Pattern end AS Pattern,
LEN(case when Pattern = '' then 'BLANK' else Pattern end) Length,
COUNT(*) AS Count FROM
     ( SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(      
      REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( 
      REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE( 
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE    
      (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(col_name),'A','A'),'B','A') ,'C','A') ,'D','A') 
      ,'E','A'),'F','A') ,'G','A') ,'H','A') ,'I','A'),'J','A') ,'K','A') ,'L','A') ,'M','A')     
      ,'N','A') ,'O','A') ,'P','A')
      ,'Q','A'),'R','A') ,'S','A') ,'T','A') ,'U','A') ,'V','A') ,'W','A') ,'X','A') ,'Y','A')    
      ,'Z','A'),'8','N'),'7','N'),'6','N'),'5','N'),'4','N'),'3','N')   
      ,'2','N'),'1','N'),'0','N'),'9','N')  
    AS Pattern FROM table_name) A  GROUP BY Pattern;
```

How to convert this to a dynamic SQL so that I can iterate over all columns of a table?

**Edit**

Lets say I have a below table

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   Column1 varchar(50),
   Column2 varchar(50),
   Column3 varchar(50),
   Column4 varchar(50),
   )
INSERT INTO Data
   (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
VALUES 
   (NULL, NULL, 'ABC123', 'abc '),
   ('xyz', NULL, 'MNO300', 'XYZ123 ')
```

Now I want a output like below:

```
Count_Pat_1 --> Count is of only one data type i.e. either Alphabetic or 
Numeric
Count_Part_2 --> Count is of mixed data type i.e. contains both alphabet and 
number

Col_name    Count_Pat_1    Count_Pat_2  Blank
Column1          1               0       1        
Column2          0               0       2
Column3          0               2       0
Column4          1               1       0
```

How can I generate the above table? Clearly I need to resort to Dynamic SQL where the entire `sql` string needs to be set as variable.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N''

SELECT @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @stm = N'' THEN N'' ELSE N',' END +
 '('+
 '''' + c.name + ''', '+
 'CASE '+
    'WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ' +
    'ELSE 0 ' +
 'END, ' +
 'CASE '+
    'WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' IS NOT NULL THEN LEN(' + 
  QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') - ** the above SQL script ***
  FROM sys.columns c
  JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
  WHERE t.name = 'Data'
```

But inserting the above SQL script at the place as indicated by ** will not be giving the output properly.

Hence any hints would be appreciated. 
SQL Server version: 2016

Comment: Start with the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I have already started! Thanks for your comment. But if you can throw some hints, will be appreciated. As I am completely novice to SQL Server

Comment: Explaining the problem you are trying to solve and providing context is always a helpful start.

Comment: How do you want to `iterate over all columns of a table` ? Please show some example

Comment: @Squirrel: As per your suggestions, I have edited the question. Kindly see whether you can provide any hints or answer?

Comment: @DaleK: Question is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dynamic SQL the trick is to get it working as static SQL first and then convert it to dynamic SQL. Some notes:

1. To get multiple rows, 1 for each column consider using `union all`.
2. To get a count of a `case` you'll need to use `sum`.
3. I've used some possible logic to get a `count` of one data type or mixed data type but you may find you need more precise logic.

```
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    SELECT @Sql = @Sql
      + CASE WHEN @Sql = '' THEN 'SELECT ' ELSE ' UNION ALL SELECT ' END
      + '''' + c.[name] + ''' ColumnName'
      + ', SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' IS NOT NULL AND ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' NOT LIKE ''%[^0-9.]%'' OR ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' NOT LIKE ''%[0-9.]%'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Count_Pat_1]'
      + ', SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' IS NOT NULL AND ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' LIKE ''%[^0-9.]%'' AND ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' LIKE ''%[0-9.]%'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Count_Pat_2]'
      + ', SUM(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Blank]'
      + ' FROM Data'
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.[name] = 'Data';

    -- print @Sql; -- For debugging
    exec sp_executesql @Sql;
```

Returns as requested:

```
ColumnName  | Count_Pat_1   | Count_Pat_2   | Blank
---------------------------------------------------
Column1     | 1             | 0             | 1
Column2     | 0             | 0             | 2
Column3     | 0             | 2             | 0
Column4     | 1             | 1             | 0
```